# Htaccess rule works on online checker, but not in the wild

Tags: .htaccess

I'm being driven potty by an .htaccess rule at the moment, and I just can't get it to work. It looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Workaround for incorrect URL in email
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/used-cars/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=1
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.co.uk/used-cars/index.php?page=1&c=main&m=search&manufacturer=&model=&pricemin=&pricemax=&branch=&postcode=example&bodystyle=&maxage=&transmission=&fueltype=&colour=&co2=&rfl=&filter=managersspecials [R=301,L]
```

It should convert this URL:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/used-cars/index.php?page=1
```

Into this:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/used-cars/index.php?page=1&c=main&m=search&manufacturer=&model=&pricemin=&pricemax=&branch=&postcode=example&bodystyle=&maxage=&transmission=&fueltype=&colour=&co2=&rfl=&filter=managersspecials
```

It works on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, but not in the wild. Any idea why? Obviously, that tester isn't 100% accurate, but I can't puzzle out why it's not working.

Comment: How does it not work, what happens?

Comment: The redirect does not happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Rule :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /used-cars/index.php\?page=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.co.uk/used-cars/index.php?page=1&c=main&m=search&manufacturer=&model=&pricemin=&pricemax=&branch=&postcode=example&bodystyle=&maxage=&transmission=&fueltype=&colour=&co2=&rfl=&filter=managersspecials [QSA,NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't appear to be matching

Comment: I have tested it on my apache server, redirection is working fine but i am a **414 Request uri too long error** its because You are redirecting "index.php" to "index.php" itself.